# GuzzleHttp\Exception\InvalidArgumentException IDN conversion failed

Tags: laravel, guzzle

after i added product data into database, this error page show me instead of routing to product page.
But, data is successful inserted.

[image]

**ProductsController.php**

```php
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $slug = $this->getSlug($request);

        $dataType = Voyager::model('DataType')->where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();

        // Check permission
        $this->authorize('add', app($dataType->model_name));

        // Validate fields with ajax
        $val = $this->validateBread($request->all(), $dataType->addRows);

        if ($val->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['errors' => $val->messages()]);
        }

        if (!$request->ajax()) {
            $requestNew = $request;
            $requestNew['price'] = $request->price * 100;

            $data = $this->insertUpdateData($requestNew, $slug, $dataType->addRows, new $dataType->model_name());

            event(new BreadDataAdded($dataType, $data));

            $this->updateProductCategories($request, $data->id);

            return redirect()
                ->route("voyager.{$dataType->slug}.index")
                ->with([
                        'message'    => __('voyager.generic.successfully_added_new')." {$dataType->display_name_singular}",
                        'alert-type' => 'success',
                    ]);
        }
    }
```

Plz help me